# Text Style not applied when Xamarin Forms is initialized

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a UWP app and try out Embedded Xamarin Forms. The embedding itself works so far. But I noticed that certain TextStyles do no longer work after I initialized Forms.

Without Forms:
[image]

After Forms.Init:
[image]

The only difference is this Line in the App.xaml.cs:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
```

The Code of the TextBlock is:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TitlePage"
                   Text="Hello"
                   Style="{StaticResource PageTitleStyle}" />
```

And the style:

```
<Style x:Key="PageTitleStyle"
       TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="SemiLight" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="{StaticResource LargeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming"
            Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
            Value="NoWrap" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="{StaticResource PageTitleMargin}" />
</Style>
```

I created a minimal example which you can find here:  https://github.com/NPadrutt/EmbeddedFormsTest

Versions:

- VS 15.5.2
- Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);`, it will load the `ResourceDictionary` which defined in Xamarin. So that after this code line invoked, the text may show the style defined in Xamarin Forms, not the style you defined in UWP. Details you can check the code snippet of [`Init`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Forms.cs) method.

**Updated:**

The `Init` method merge the style by this code line

```
return new Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary {
Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Resources.xbf")
```

And you will find the following style in [Resource.xaml](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Resources.xaml) in Xamarin.

```
<Style x:Key="PageTitleStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

Which has same `x:key` (PageTitleStyle) as you defined so that your style will be override. **Just change the `x:key` of your style** it will not be influenced by the Xamarin resources,for example `PageTitleStyle2`.

If you want to use the style you defined in UWP app for the Xamarin Forms, you could use [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/). `TextBlock` is the native control for UWP, the correspondent control in Xamarin Forms is `Label`. Details please see [Renderer Base Classes and Native Controls](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers/). You should have a `Label` control in Xamarin Forms and create a custom renderer for `Label` and set the style with target type is `TextBlock` in UWP. For example:

```
public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.Style= (Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)App.Current.Resources["PageTitleStyle"];
    }
}
```

For more samples you could reference [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/windows/Custom%20Renderers/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be sure, when I Init xamarin Forms all styles for my native UWP controls will stop working? Since the Textblock shown above is in a native MainPage of UWP.

Comment: @NPadrutt, Not for all. As I mentioned above, the `init` method merge the `Resource` in Xamarin which just contains the style same name as you defined. I will update my reply to make it more clearly.

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft AH, alright. that explains it. My native UWP style was overriden by the xamarin Style. I just had to adjust the name for my native UWP style. Thanks for the explanation!! :)